# ObjectOutputStream duplicate output

Tags: java, serializable, objectoutputstream

Cannot even find the problem itself in this case. When the program reads from *objects.dat*, the output is only the variables of the last objects in the array.
[Program output screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Lf4.jpg)
I have combed through the code several times and cannot find the problem. As far as I am aware everything is smooth up until it tries to serialize and write/read the objects to "objects.dat". If anybody could give me a hint as to what the problem is or how to go about fixing it, I'd greatly appreciate it. I think the problem might be in either the readFile or writeFile method but I cannot be sure.

The goal is to make an object array, serialize it, write it to a file, and then read the file.

```
public class Test implements Serializable{

public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidTestScore, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput;
    final int ARRAYLENGTH;
    //get info for ARRAYLENGTH and make a TestScore array.
    System.out.println("How many test scores are you finding the average of? (ex. 6 tests): ");
    ARRAYLENGTH = keyboard.nextInt();
    TestScores[] scoreArray = new TestScores[ARRAYLENGTH];
    //populate scoreArray with TestScore objects.
    for (int counter = 0; counter < scoreArray.length; counter++)
    {
       System.out.println("Enter the score of test " + (counter + 1) + ": ");
       userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
       scoreArray[counter] = new TestScores(counter, userInput);

    }

    System.out.println("Now writing the object to 'objects.dat'...");
    TestScores.writeFile(scoreArray);

    System.out.println("Now reading the object from 'objects.dat'...");
    TestScores.readFile(ARRAYLENGTH);
}



 package scoresPackage;
import java.io.*;

public class TestScores implements Serializable {

    static TestScores[] scoreArray, scoreRead;
    static int score, name;

    TestScores (int test, int num) throws InvalidTestScore
    {
        name = test;
        score = num;

        if (num >= 100 || num <= 0)
           {
              throw new InvalidTestScore();
           }
    }
    public static void writeFile(TestScores[] test) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("objects.dat");
        try (ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream)) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < test.length; counter++)
            {
                objectOut.writeObject(test[counter]);
                objectOut.reset();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Writing success.");
    }
    public static void readFile(int ALENGTH) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("objects.dat");
        try (ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(inStream)) {
            scoreRead = new TestScores[ALENGTH];

            for (int counter = 0; counter < ALENGTH; counter++)
            {
                scoreRead[counter] = (TestScores) objectIn.readObject();
                System.out.println("Test " + name + " Score: " + score);

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Reading success.");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
static int score, name;
```

It has nothing to do with `ObjectOutputStream` - it means that you don't have one score and one name per *instance* of `TestScores`, but one `score` variable and one `name` *overall*. Your `TestScores` constructor is overwriting those variables, so by the time you've created the second instance, you've lost the first `name`/`score` data you requested from the user. One good way to see this would be to remove the `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` code altogether: once you've asked the user for all the information, what happens if you try to print it all out to the console? (You'll see the same behavior, basically: you'll just see the last values entered.)

You want instance fields, not static fields:

```
int score, name;
```

(Or better yet, make them private... that's not the only change I'd make to the code, but it's a starting point.)

See the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details about the difference between static fields an instance fields.

Comment: Thank you so much, and thank you for the link to the tutorial. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @KaceyVH: It's the kind of mistake a lot of relatively new developers make - there's no need to feel bad about it. It's one of those rites of passage that's good to get out of the way nice and early :)